# aligning contents in the center

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

How can i put align my contents in the navigation bar in the middle without adding padding? I do not want to increase the background. There's no details else to add. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.

```css
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 26px;
        color: white;
    }
    
    ul {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        background: #091624;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin: 20px 0;
        line-height: normal;
    }
    
    a.content,
    a:hover {
        background: #1b9bff;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        nav {
            height: 80px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        nav ul {
            position: fixed;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 40px;
            text-align: right;
            height: 60px;
        }
        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 80px;
            margin: 0 5px;
        }
        nav ul li a {
            color: white;
            font-size: 17px;
            padding: 7px 13px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    <title>Responsive Navigation Bar</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="content">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Learning Paths</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

[Image of live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWO1T.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS for wider screens, you need to remove the right-alignment:

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        nav {
            height: 80px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        nav ul {
            position: fixed;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 40px;
            /* REMOVE THIS LINE text-align: right; */
            height: 60px;
        }
```

Comment: No, I do not want it to be aligned in the center. I  want it to be in the center of the background starting from the back. As you can see in the image the it's now more towards the bottom.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid - perhaps you could make an image which shows what you _want_? I don't follow "center of the background starting from the back". Centered vertically?